# Override onClick when ticking checkbox in div block

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

Given my `onClick={() => this.activeToggle("Discharge")}` in the outer most `div`.
Is it possible to override the `onClick()` when clicking on one of the two `checkboxes`?

This is part of a accordion and it works great, but I would like to ignore the onClick event when I check one of the two checkboxes.

[**EXAMPLE (bit patchy)**](https://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/067rj0hq/)

```
const stateDischarge = {
    active: {
        display: 'inherit'
    },
    inactive: {
        display: 'none'
    }
};


var Preferences = React.createClass({
.
.
.

activeToggle: function (panel) {

    event.stopPropagation();  //  <= this is there I am trying the suggestion. but not working, so trying something else.

    switch (panel) {
        case "Demographics":
            this.setState({
                activeDemographics: !this.state.activeDemographics
            });
            break;
        case "Admission":
            this.setState({
                activeAdmission: !this.state.activeAdmission
            });
            break;
        case "Discharge":
            this.setState({
                activeDischarge: !this.state.activeDischarge
            });
            break;
        default:
            //Statements executed when none of the values match the value of the expression
            break;
    }
},
.
.
.
const stateDischarge = this.state.activeDischarge ? styles.active : styles.inactive;


    render: function() {

    <div className="panel panel-info">
        <div className="panel-heading"  onClick={() => this.activeToggle("Discharge")}>
            <h4 className="panel-title pull-left">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Discharge</a>
            </h4>
            <div className="pull-right">
                <label className="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Admission</label>
                <label className="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/>Non-Admission</label>
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" className="panel-collapse" style={stateDischarge}>
            <div className="panel-body">
                <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">

                    //Content in Accordion pannel                   

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    }
});
module.exports = Preferences;
```

Comment: I have to ask ... what is `onClick={() => this.activeToggle("Discharge")}` - not javascript, if that works I need to know how please

Comment: Well, I use it in react, but I dont think its quite a react based topic.

Comment: @JaromandaX - ES6 Arrow function syntax

Comment: no ... I mean `onclick={....}` ... i.e. no quotes around the code ... so that would be react, of course ... been a while since I dabbled in react